# Executing a function inside a variable X times

Tags: php, function, for-loop

Having the following code:

```
switch ($options['algorythm'])
{
    case 'jigsaw':
        $result = $this->jigsaw($options['count'], $options['length']);
    break;
    case 'freddy':
        $result = $this->freddy($options['count'], $options['length'], $options['characters']);
    break;
}


for($i=0; $i < $options['count']; $i++)
{
    echo $result."<br/>";
}
```

How can I execute the function inside `$result` the times defined in `count`? Because as for now, it will only repeat the same result that many times.

Comment: It's not clear what you want to do. There's nothing in `$result` that depends on `$i`, so you'll still get the same result each time.

Comment: Note that, if you change your functions to accept the options hash rather than enumerated arguments, you could simply use `call_user_func(($this, $options['algorythm']), $options);` inside your loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way would be to move your `switch` inside your loop:

```
for($i=0; $i < $options['count']; $i++)
{
    switch ($options['algorythm'])
    {
        case 'jigsaw':
            $result = $this->jigsaw($options['count'], $options['length']);
        break;
        case 'freddy':
            $result = $this->freddy($options['count'], $options['length'], $options['characters']);
        break;
    }

    echo $result;
}
```

After that's working, you can try being clever with [`call_user_func`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php).